# Deleting an unnamed orphaned remote branch in git

Tags: git

Someone on our team pushed a series of commits to the remote repository that are orphaned. That is, the first commit had no parent. The subsequent ones are descendants of the first. There is also no name on the branch. Graphically, it looks like this

```
master
o Commit #4
|               (no branch)
o commit #3     o commit #7
|               |
o commit #2     o commit #6
|               |
o commit #1     o commit #5
```

I want to delete commits 5-7. I tried creating a branch at commit 5. Then, commits 6 and 7 were listed as being on that branch. Then, I tried pruning the branch, but to no avail.

How can I do this?

UPDATE: I think the issue had to do with mismatched branch names. The developer somehow named the new branch on the remote as master. There was already a master originally, which still existed on my local. So, (I use GitExt) when viewing the repository locally, I think it confused GitExt and showed the local branch as not having any name. When I reset master branch back to the original branch on the remote, the new branch no longer had any references and disappeared. Problem solved, I think.

Comment: If there are no pointers to it, then it should be removed during garbage collection.

Comment: How are you able to reference commits 5, 6, or 7 if they *have no branch* are they tagged?

Comment: _Graphically, it looks like this_ what tool did you use to construct that graph? Git doesn't have output like that AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

[Sukima's question-comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121803/deleting-an-unnamed-orphaned-remote-branch-in-git#comment71411746_42121803) is the key to understanding all of this.

Within a Git repository, the commit graph—the DAG—is represented as a collection of commit objects.  Each object is identified, as usual, by its hash ID, and each commit has some number of parent object IDs (zero or more, but usually 1) inside it.  Git uses the parent links to construct the graph, but in order to *begin* this graph construction process, it must have some way to identify the "starting points".  (Other version control systems, including Mercurial, use other techniques and do not need this list of starting points.)

These starting points are Git's *references*.  The two most commonly viewed references are branch and tag names, but there are additional "regular" references, all under names starting with `refs/`, and some special ones like `HEAD` (when `HEAD` is detached) and `FETCH_HEAD` (in a repository in which one has run `git fetch`).  There are also extra-special references: the *index* (aka staging area, aka cache) keeps direct references to "blobs" (file objects stored inside the repository database—these do not participate in the commit graph, but are all part of the same overall storage scheme).

It's quite normal to create an object, then abandon it.  Commits and blobs are the most typical, but any of the four object types can go through this process.  We abandon old commits when we copy them to new commits with `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`, for instance.<sup>1</sup>  We abandon blob objects when we `git add` a file, then realize it's not done yet, edit it some more, and `git add` it *again* before committing.  Each `git add` copies the file itself into the repository as a blob object, but until we `git commit` the result, it's only referenced via the index, and re-`add`-ing a new version overwrites the old index entry.

Git can, and occasionally does, do a full sweep of *every* repository object, which will find objects that have no starting point that can lead to them.  These are sometimes called *unreachable* objects.<sup>2</sup>  The two user-facing commands that do this—these still very maintenance-y, and not usually necessary for most users—are the repository consistency checker `git fsck`, and the *garbage collector* `git gc`.  Because they do this kind of full-sweep, they are relatively slow.<sup>3</sup>

Because it is slow, automatic garbage collection is done "in the background": various commands spin off `git gc` automatically as needed, to discard unreferenced / unreachable commits and files.  This means that the background cleanup can vie with normal Git activity, which can be creating *new* objects that are not yet referenced, but will be as soon as the command finishes.  For instance, the GC might be running at the same time as a `git commit` command.  If the GC found a newly-created commit just before it got added to the branch, and deleted the commit, that would be bad.  Hence, for safety, automatic GC avoids removing anything created within the last 14 days by default: this gives `git commit` 336 hours to finish up, which should usually be enough time. :-)

You can always find any existing Git object by its raw hash ID: that's how Git accesses each object, whether in a slow full-sweep operation, where it simply enumerates every ID inside the repository, or in a faster operation that starts with a starting-point, such as a branch or tag reference.  Hence, *if* the commits really are unreachable, but *are* still in the repository, you can view them by their hash ID.  But eventually, the garbage collector will run *and* they will be at least 14 days old.  At this point, GC will *remove* them and they will be gone for good.<sup>4</sup>

Normally you don't need to care about any of this, but if you have accidentally put something sensitive, such as a plaintext password or key or certificate, into the repository, you might want to remove it more quickly.  This is difficult (see the footnotes), and by the time you have noticed that the barn door is open, the horses may have been cloned anyway,<sup>5</sup> so it's wise to invalidate the certificate, even if you do manage to find and delete the offending Git object.

---

<sup>1</sup>These abandoned commits are normally retained through *reflogs*.  There's one reflog per ordinary `refs/` name-space reference, plus one big one for the special `HEAD` reference.  Items in the reflog live for at least 30 days by default, and sometimes for up to 90 days.  (Both time values are configurable: see `gc.reflogExpire` and `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable`.)  But eventually these expire as well, after which the objects to which they point may become truly unreferenced, and hence candidates for GC.

<sup>2</sup>The word *unreferenced* could be used to talk specifically about a commit or other object that does not have a *direct* reference, with the word *unreachable* being used for, e.g., a commit that has another commit referring to it, but the *other* commit has nothing referring to *it*.  That is, visually, we might have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     E--F    <-- branch
      \
       G--H
```

The last two commits, `G--H`, have no name at all, but we might call only `H` *unreferenced* while both are *unreachable*.  But Git is not consistent about this: `git fsck` uses the word *dangling* to describe commit `H`.

<sup>3</sup>This GC process is quite reminiscent of some programming languages' "mark and sweep" GC.  For instance, see many Lisp implementations, going all the way back to 1959.  See also the [Wikipedia page on GC in programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).  Git's GC does not use (nor desire) reference counting, nor any of the sort of live-action real-time GC systems, since GC can mostly run in the background and simply lock pack files for short periods.  Of course, Git's objects form a DAG, which by definition contains no cycles, unlike Lisp data structures.  Nonetheless, mark-and-sweep is simple and efficient and works well here.

<sup>4</sup>This glosses over *packed* objects.  Objects can be either *loose*, in which case they are stored in a compressed form but in individual files, or *packed*.  Packed objects are stored en masse in a single file whose name ends in `.pack`.  (There can be multiple instances of these `.pack` files, with each one being self-contained.)  Packed objects can still be GC-ed if necessary, but it's not as easy: the pack must be *re-packed*, using `git repack`.  The new pack will not retain unreferenced objects (`git repack` calls them "unreachable" and it has a slightly different meaning there).  If you have the old pack file deleted, that will, at long last, discard the object.  But you can mark some packs as precious, by adding `<name>.keep` files; those will *never* be deleted automatically.

Note that the main point of packing objects is to make them both faster and slower to access (in a complicated way, trying to keep more recent objects faster) while *delta-compressing* them against each other within the pack to shrink disk space usage.  The garbage collector `git gc` normally handles all of this for you automatically.

<sup>5</sup>A normal ordinary `git clone` only clones referenced / reachable objects.  But even if a secret or sensitive file was always unreachable, it's possible for an attacker who knows one of the commit IDs to use the Git transports to access the object, or information about the object.  See [the description of known transfer data leaks in the Git documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/transfer-data-leaks.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I can't upvote yet.

Answer (score 1):

Commits that are not referred by any branch will be removed by the git garbage collector. No need to do anything.

Comment: Maybe they have a tag to them?